# Database query result to display in Label VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, vb.net-2010

I have a label in which I want to display my database query result. But the label displaying only first row not all the records. Can anyone here could help me with this? Tried searching but I found other answers confusing. Please help me.

Here is what I have so far.

**FrontEnd**

```
<asp:Label ID="Resulttext" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

**Backend**

```
Protected Sub getUser()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("myconnectionhere")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("mysqlhere", conn)
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Resulttext.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Fullname").ToString
        End If
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solve the problem and here is the answer.

```
  If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Resulttext.Text = dt.Rows(i)("Fullname").ToString & " " & Resulttext.Text
        Next

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Resulttext.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Fullname").ToString
```

You are writing above code for display record in the Lable.

Meaning of above code is `dt.Rows(RowIndex)(ColumnIndex/"Column valuse")`

You passed 0 in the RowIndex Means it gives you First row and passed "FullName" in column value , So it gives fullname value of First row.

That's why it displays only one record.

For display all the value of FullName you have to change your query as below.

```
select distinct t1.id,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + FullName
          FROM yourtable t2
          where t1.id = t2.id
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS fullname
from yourtable t1;
```

Thus it gives fullName as comma separated and then you can write code

```
Resulttext.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Fullname").ToString
```

And it gives `CSV` for `fullname` and displays in the label

Comment: No my query is right. What I'm asking is in label it only display one record which that must be multiple. I tried to run my query in SQL and its working the query result is 2 fullname ex. Joana and Ric the label only display Joana not the both record. That's my concern here. Thank you.

Comment: please increase the label width, It may be issue of label width.